# Execute tests in RubyMine causes "uninitialized constant Spring::Client::Run::UNIXSocket" on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, rubymine

In RubyMine, I try to run tests in debug (equivalent to `rails test`, but with debug mode in RubyMine). I get this log in RubyMine console:

```
Testing started at 08:44 ...
C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\ruby.exe C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.beta4/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 55232 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 55233 -- C:/Users/[ANONYMOUS]/bin/rails test
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.0.beta4, debase 0.2.2, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:55232
Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant Spring::Client::Run::UNIXSocket
Did you mean?  Socket
               IPSocket
               UDPSocket
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:26:in `connect'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:31:in `call'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    C:/Users/[ANONYMOUS]/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Users/[ANONYMOUS]/bin/rails:3:in `load'
    C:/Users/[ANONYMOUS]/bin/rails:3:in `<top (required)>'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems like RubyMine tries to run against some UNIX configuration, but I couldn't find anything related to this in my files.

I run RubyMine with `Ruby 2.3.3`, on `Windows 7`, `RubyMine 2018.1.4`.

When I run tests without the debug mode, everything is fine.

How could I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: better late than never, but I've just spent ages trying to run spring on my windows platform and got the same error as you're recieving only to read from their README that windows isn't supported.

Comment: any reason why my answer has not been marked as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall spring as it's not supported on Windows.

From thier [README](https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/master/README.md):

> Spring makes extensive use of Process.fork, so won't be able to provide a speed up on platforms which don't support forking (Windows, JRuby).

To uninstall:

1. 'Unspring' your bin/ executables:

   ```
   spring binstub --remove --all
   ```
2. Remove spring from your Gemfile
3. Recreate your gemlock file by running:

   ```
   bundle install
   ```